# is there any way to make me Can know if this facebook video link is valid for a real public video?

Tags: facebook, video, embed

the case is that I will embed facebook video Iframe or using react-facebook but validation for facebook link is not enough as it still can be a valid facebook video link but it is private or deleted or even not exist cause I don't check its valiation according to real facebook database for example but according regex.

Comment: the regex used to check facebook video link https://www.regextester.com/94994

Comment: You would need to make an API request with the video ID you are extracting. But for page videos, you would have to submit your app for the Public Page Content Access feature first, and for user videos, the user would have to login to your app and grant you permission to read their videos first.